# How to remove query string variable from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to remove query string variable name from htaccess ? I have following structure.

```
http://localhost/newsite/category?id=News
http://localhost/newsite/category?id=Entertainment
http://localhost/newsite/category?id=Technology
```

I want to change

```
http://localhost/newsite/News/
http://localhost/newsite/Entertainment/
http://localhost/newsite/Technology/
```

like this. I tried rewriting in htaccess, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ category.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
RewriteRule ^newsite/([^./]+)/?$ newsite/category?id=$1 [NC,L]
```